# Check if word is in string and replace the string

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need a method to check if the `[msg valueForKey:@"text"]` contain the `currentString` and if it does it should be replace with the character `*` depending on the length of the word.

How can I do this? The code below is how far I've come:

```
NSDictionary *msg = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

for (NSString *currentString in badwords)
{
    if ([[msg valueForKey:@"text"]]) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your calling the array “badwords”, I assume you’re trying to create an obscenity filter. Trying to filter "badwords" is a nightmare. Your approach, and the approach of the currently accepted answer, is super naive for a obscenity filter and will lead to results like “The US Cons***ution” and “cl***ic muscle cars” as [Atwood describes here.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/)

Comment: I see. So what would be the approach then?

Comment: This would probably be one of those rare times when I would go library shopping - or at least browse some open-source repositories. If you must implement it yourself, for whatever reason, consider letting Apple’s frameworks do some of the work for you. For example let `NSString` break the string into words for you by using `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` and passing `NSStringEnumerationByWords` for the option and then check if the sub-string passed into the block is in the “badwords” array/set. Of course this requires the set to contain all permutations of a “badword”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` method:

```
NSString *newString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:currentString
                                                           withString:replacementString];
```

You would create the replacement string like this:

```
NSMutableString *replacementString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < currentString.length; i++)
{
    [replacementString appendString:@"*"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the NSString class reference. There are a whole family of methods supporting this sort of thing. For your specific need, look at methods like rangeOfString: or stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
NSDictionary *msg = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *redactedString = [msg valueForKey:@"text"];
for (NSString *currentString in badwords)
    redactedString = [redactedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:currentString
                                                       withString:@"*"];
NSLog(redactedString);
```

Adapted from @reecon.

Answer (score 0):

I found an github project which helped to achieve this. I hope someone else can use this.

https://github.com/IslandOfDoom/IODProfanityFilter